# Count how many specific values appear between two defined values in column

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
   value
open
id1
id1
id2
close
open
open
close
open
id1
id2
close
open
id1
id1
close
close
open
close
open
id1
id2
id2
id2
close
```

```
df <- c("id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "open", "close", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "close", "open", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "close", "open", "open", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "close", "open", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "close", "open", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "close", "open", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "close", "open", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "close", "open", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "close", "open", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "close", "open", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "close", "open", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "close", "open", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "close", "open")
```

How could i count how many "id1" and "id2" between each "open" and "close"? Desired result can look like this:

```
{id1:2,0,1,2,0,2}

{id2:1,0,1,0,0,2}
```

How could i do that? I shouldn't consider cases when there is "open" but no "close" after it or there is "close" but no "open" before it

Here

Answer (score 1):

**PLEASE** give us some [reproducible data](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) next time. The below does what you requested.

```
value <- c("open", 
"id1",
"id1",
"id2",
"close",
"open",
"open",
"close",
"open",
"id1",
"id2",
"close",
"close")
openid <- which(value == "open")
closeid <- which(value == "close")
id1 <- sapply(1:length(openid), function(x) sum("id1"==value[openid[x]:closeid[x]]))
id2 <- sapply(1:length(openid), function(x) sum("id2"==value[openid[x]:closeid[x]]))
> id1;id2
[1] 2 0 1 1
[1] 1 0 1 1
```

---

**EDIT** with your provided data, it works perfectly fine as well.

```
df <- c("id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "open", "close", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "close", "open", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "close", "open", "open", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "close", "open", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "close", "open", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "close", "open", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "close", "open", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "close", "open", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "close", "open", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "close", "open", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "close", "open", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "close", "open", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id2", "close", "open")
openid <- which(value == "open")
closeid <- which(value == "close")
id1 <- sapply(1:length(openid), function(x) sum("id1"==value[openid[x]:closeid[x]]))
id2 <- sapply(1:length(openid), function(x) sum("id2"==value[openid[x]:closeid[x]]))
```

see results:

```
> id2
[1] 1 0 1 1
> id1
[1] 2 0 1 1
> openid
[1] 1 6 7 9
> closeid
[1]  5  8 12 13
```

Comment: it says Error in openid[x]:closeid[x] : NA/NaN argument

Comment: that's probly because you have `NA`'s in `openid` or `closeid`. with my data it works. If you had provided toy data I could have done it on yours. check if you have `Open` instead of `open` in your data, or check that the vector name is actually `value` of course...

Comment: i added a reproducible example of vector

Comment: value <- c(
  "open",
  "id1", 
  "id1",
  "id2",
  "close",
  "open",
  "open",
  "close",
  "open",
  "id1",
  "id2",
  "close",
  "open",
  "id1",
  "id1",
  "close",
  "close",
  "open",
  "close",
  "open",
  "id1",
  "id2",
  "id2",
  "id2",
  "close")

Comment: no it is not a reproducible example. it should indlude `"`. This is important because it means you haven't tried the problem on your side with this data. Try on your side first, then tell me if it works

Comment: a problem is that my openid has more elements than closeid

Comment: well then crop the vectors or edit your question, I can't guess your data...

Comment: i added my actual dataframe to question. try with it please

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `tidyverse` approach to the problem. You can create groups that start with "open" in your vector, and only include groups where a "close" also exists. Then, `slice` to analyze the ids that present before "close". Next, `summarise` to get the number of ids for each group.

I added `complete` so you would have zero counts for those with just "open" and "close" and no ids in between.

```
library(tidyverse)

data.frame(val = df) %>%
  group_by(grp = cumsum(val == "open")) %>%
  filter(any(val == "close")) %>%
  slice(seq_len(min(which(val == "close"), n()))) %>%
  group_by(grp, val) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  complete(grp, val, fill = list(count = 0)) %>%
  filter(val != "open" & val != "close") %>%
  dplyr::select(-grp)
```

**Output**

```
   val   count
   <chr> <dbl>
 1 id1       0
 2 id2       0
 3 id1       6
 4 id2      26
 5 id1       6
 6 id2      36
 7 id1       2
 8 id2      19
 9 id1       1
10 id2      20
11 id1       2
12 id2      14
13 id1       6
14 id2      26
15 id1       6
16 id2      20
17 id1       3
18 id2      26
19 id1       4
20 id2      13
21 id1       2
22 id2       9
23 id1       6
24 id2      26
```